# how rand() works in awk

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to sample the 2nd column of a csv file (any number of samples is fine) using `awk` and `rand()`. But, I noticed that I always end up with the same number of samples

```
cat toy.txt | awk -F',' 'rand()<0.2 {print $2}' | wc -l
```

I explored and it seems `rand()` is not working as I expected. For example, a in the following seems to always be 1,

```
cat toy.txt | awk -F',' 'a=rand() a<0.2 {print a}'
```

Why?

Comment: Just curious - what do you think `a=rand() a<0.2` means in your second script?

Comment: is similar to typing `rand()<0.2`, isn't it? Just wanted to print the value for `rand()`.

Comment: No, that'd be `{a=rand()} a<0.2`. I'm really not sure what awk will make of what you wrote but my best guess is it might be equivalent to `(a=( (rand()a) < 0.2 ? 1 : 0) ? 1 : 0)`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks @EdMorton

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Numeric-Functions.html):

> CAUTION: In most awk implementations, including gawk, rand() starts generating numbers from the same starting number, or seed, each time you run awk. Thus, a program generates the same results each time you run it. The numbers are random within one awk run but predictable from run to run. This is convenient for debugging, but if you want a program to do different things each time it is used, you must change the seed to a value that is different in each run. To do this, use srand().

Answer (score 2):

So, to apply what's been pointed out in the man page, and duplicated all over this forum and elsewhere on the Internet, I like to use:

```
awk -v rseed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(rseed);}{print rand()" "$0}'
```

The **rseed** variable is optional, but included here, because sometimes it helps me to have a deterministic/repeatable random series for simulations when other variables can change, etc.